How to glue a browser window to the desktop?
A student with ADHD has asked me for a way to to "glue" his school schedule to the desktop so he will not be able to close or ignore it. It's in a Google Docs document, and it should be dynamic, so the solution cannot be a screenshot of a page.
I tried looking for dynamic screensavers or dashboards but everything is complicated or Google prevents it due to security restrictions.
Any ideas on how to achieve this for him?

Autohotkey can set a window always on bottom, and chrome can be launched in app mode to make it more of a window than a browser. The student can still close the window though, I don't think you can actually prevent that in any way unless you create the program yourself in .net, which is not too hard to do, but the web browser component there may not be the best, so not sure how that works with the google schedule.

try asking at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
